# How do I synchronize 2 sites, one installed with Composer and one from downloaded zip?

Tags: 8, installation

I have two sites:
one, local, installed with `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev mysitelocal --stability dev --no-interaction`
another one, remote, installed from `drupal-8.7.6.zip` that has been downloaded from drupal.org, the files in the archive have been copied to remote location and then `myremotesite/core/install.php` has been executed.

Of course, folders structure is different in the two locations.
My question is: how to sync from my local to my remote site?

Comment: Absolutely opinion-based thing. My would be: Don't do it that way. Get a server that has Composer. Have your local site connected to some Git, composer require dependencies, Drush do this and that, and then commit Composer json and lock and the exported config. On your live site git pull, run composer install and import config.

Comment: In fact this is not a composer question at all. Even if both sites had been installed via composer you wouldn't be able to sync them. Important is to clone the site first. Whether you use composer install or copy the files via ftp (not recommended but possible) doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, it is possible to convert a zip/tar install into a `drupal-composer/drupal-project`, so the remote site can be fixed up and local/remote handled with the current best practice workflow. An answer can describe how to do that (though we may already a near or exact dup for that scenario).